# SQL version of a recent Stack Overflow data-dump

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, data-dump

I am trying to find a sql version of a recent stack overflow data-dump (2012 or 2013). I have been able to download an XML version but my programming knowledge is too limited to convert it in an sql format. I run MAMP (PHP-MySQL) on a Mac.

I am aware that Stack Overflow only provides an XML version of the dataset, but I have seen discussions about people being able to convert the datasets into SQL.

I have seen that a 2009 version of the data dump used to be available in the past, but not anymore. Does anyone have a link to download a newer version of the database in an sql format? I am sure such a link would be also useful to other people as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to query with this that you can't do with the XML (with your current programming skills)

Comment: We only provide the data dump in XML format.

Comment: I am trying to do some linguistic analyses on questions and answers. I am pretty sure there are other ways to do this, but mine is in php-mysql.

Comment: Oded: Yes, I know that. I am wondering if somebody already converted one of the datasets in SQL for their own projects, and could make it available for me and other people who might need it. Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53613/148672

Comment: Thanks for the link. This method requires knowing the database structure, which I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, you could use the very cool [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). It allows you to construct queries on almost every part of the public data dumps, including users, posts, votes, and more.

It may or may not suit your needs, as there are some strict regulations regarding how the queries are run, but as long as you're not doing something that takes an *astronomical* amount of time, you should be fine.

It's also updated weekly (usually on sundays) so it's probably as recent as possible, if you aren't a dev.

Comment: This is actually a GREAT idea. It is perfect for someone like me with limited programming knowledge. And I can export csvs. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As @Oded mentioned, the data dumps are currently only provided in XML format. If you would also like for them to be provided in SQL format, you should probably raise a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: I do not think me requesting a feature would be relevant. I am not experienced enough. I know that some people have converted data-dumps into sql in the past. if someone had a direct link to download a converted data-dump that I could use in MySQL, it would be very helpful. I have also spent a lot of time reading related questions here, and I am pretty sure I would not be the only one beneffiting from such a link.

Comment: A serious problem with that kind of request is that there *isn't* a "SQL format". There are many different RDBMs each with their own format (or formats) a few of which can inter-operate some of the time. For all of XMLs many, heinous sins it *is* well specified.

Comment: You might find this project helpful: https://github.com/1123/StackExchangeImporter. It allows importing the XML dumps into relational databases using JPA, and thus should support most relational databases including MySQL.